# what is the pros/cons to have unique&unpredictable id in url

Tags: url, seo, web-crawler

I'm considering to use url pattern like below:

```
example.com/item/r6B0PmUmx07O/just-one-item
example.com/item/r6B0PGgwPJWl/yet-another-item
```

the part before slug is an unique and unpredictable id for an item.

compare with url like

```
example.com/item/1001/just-one-item
example.com/item/1002/yet-another-item
```

is this way bad for SEO?

or will it be bad for crawling by the search engine?(since the crawler cannot 'guess' the next item's id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how many popular crawlers try to increment number values in URL to hit the page. 
They generaly try to traverse by links.

But consider hiding some info from malicious users. If you can reach any info about your users (by example.com/user/1001) there is generally wrong idea to have sequential UID's. It's not mean to be a part of security but sometimes it's good to difficult access to your data. So the competition will have some difficulties when guessing how much products you have on stock :)

Consider supplying dynamical sitemap with links to all your products. This make you sure that every crawler will hit all your items no matter what key it has.

Comment: i think you're right, though it looks a little ugly but it should not make any different to the search engine.